# Need to check the rosinstall for openni

Tags: ros, rosinstall, openni-kinect, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm using ROS Electric in Ubuntu 10.04 lucyd. I have followed the full installation process and actualy I have already made some nodes succesfully. I want to use the openni_kinect pakage. I'm following this tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect#Ubuntu_installation-1 and it says that I need rosinstall. For that I'm following the next tutorial http://ros.org/wiki/rosinstall. Everything seems to be all right until this point sudo easy_install -U rosinstall. But when the tutorial says "After installation, rosinstall writes a bash setup file, called setup.bash, into PATH. Source this file to configure your environment variables." I dont know where to find that file. I wrote rosinstall --version and I got rosinstall 0.5.26. So I want to think that everything is ok whit rosinstall... but when I return to the kinect tutorial in 3.2 the make or even the make debian commands brings the following: GIT: Program not foun /  Built error 127. Is something wrong with the rosinstall? Or do I need something extra? I have already tried sudo apt-get install git, but it say git package is not aviable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12969/need-to-check-the-rosinstall-for-openni/) by [ing_jluispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1760/ing_jluispr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you're using Ubuntu, you should follow *Ubuntu Installation*, not *Source based installation*. All you need to do is

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-openni-kinect
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-02-10**:
You don't need to run rosmake on packages you've installed using apt-get. "Failed to contact master" likely indicates a network configuration problem. Take a look at the troubleshooting wiki page (http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Troubleshooting#Common_Problems).

**Comment by [ing_jluispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1760/ing_jluispr/) on 2012-02-10**:
I tried, then a aply rosmake to the package and when I'm trying tu run the openni_traker node I get the following Failed to contact master